# Random forest vs Random Forest tuned with caret

Tags: r, random-forest, caret

Looking for some help please. I have used the randomForest package extensively and have been happy with its performance. I am currently writing a journal paper investigating match outcomes in sport, predicting the outcome of matches from 33 performance indicators.

I need to use caret to produce the randomForest package as I wish to use Lime to explain outcomes in a testing data set. Lime can't accept a model from randomForest, only from a randomForest wrapped via caret.

When I use random forest I get a prediction accuracy of approx 76% on the training data set, when I tune in caret I get an accuracy of 100%.

Is this sort of improvement common? Or am I making a mistake? Would be really grateful is somebody could check my code.

My data set is named model.data

```
# Create model with default parameters

control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)

seed <- 7

metric <- "Accuracy"

set.seed(seed)

mtry <- sqrt(ncol(model.data))

tunegrid <- expand.grid(.mtry=mtry)

rf_group <- train(Outcome~., data=model.data, method="rf", metric=metric, tuneGrid=tunegrid, trControl=control)

print(rf_group)


# predict the outcome on the training set
Test.Predict <- predict(rf_group, model.data)
# compare predicted outcome and true outcome
confusionMatrix(Test.Predict, as.factor(model.data$Outcome))
```

Comment: 0. Welcome to the CV community. 1. Performance metrics based on the training set are misleading; avoid them. Use/report proper resampling-based measurements (e.g. like the ones `caret` report when using `repeatedcv`); report the variability of the estimates too. 2. If you are writing an article for a journal, assuming that the editor/reviewers follow simple good practices, they won't care for any metrics coming from the training set. 3. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you for this appreciate your time and comments

Comment: clarification requests: is this 100% on the training set or the test set?  Did the learner ever touch in any way the test set when going through the process of selecting the weights or parameters?  Can you provide information about the data (number of columsn, type of output)... ?